# como hago un array de string

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda sobre como hacer el array con *string*, en`char tipo_zapato[] = {"A","B","C"}`. Siempre me sale un error que dice:

`[Error] too many initializers for 'char []',  este es mi codigo:`

Mi código es el siguiente:

````
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char descripcion_l[30], booleano, referencia2;
    char tipo_zapato[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
    int referencia1, talla1, cantidad_z, costo_unidad, costo_total=0, precio_unidad=0, precio_total=0, utilidad_unidad=0, utilidad_total=0, porcentaje_utilidad;```
````

Comment: El identificador `tipo_zapato` es un array de caracteres y solo puede ser inicializado con una cadena. Si quieres agregar diversas cadenas, debes utilizar un array de punteros a `char`. Ej: `char* tipo_zapato[] = {"a", "b", "c"};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia los **`"`** por **`'`**.

Usas **`"`** para string.

```
char tipo_zapato[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Si un dato es tipo `char` debe ir entre comillas simples `'a'`. Si es tipo `string` entre comillas dobles `"a"`

Tipo `char`:

```
char tipo_zapato[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Tipo `string`:

```
string* pStr = new string[3] { "a", "b", "c"};
```

Comment: No hace falta usar memoria dinamica. Con esto basta: `std::string s[]{"a", "b", "c"};`